# Geewax jQuery checktree code issue

Tags: jquery, treeview

I have a small display issue when using [Geewax's jQuery checktree functionality](http://static.geewax.org/checktree/index.html) that has baffled me and I am wondering whether you can help me out or point me in the right direction.

I have replicated the page locally on my pc and ensured all the necessary images, css file and js files are within the folder. The list of top level collapsed items displays correctly and are lined up.

Then I copied the entire folder onto a web server running IIS and launched the page but the top level list elements are indented as per the screenshot attached.

The only thing that is different is from where the page is being run and I have used IE8 in both cases.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - so for anyone else stumbling upon this post with the same issue IE8 was running in compatibility mode since I have the web developer toolbar installed and the following style was causing the indentation of the top level list elements: ul.tree li { padding: 4px 0 0 0; } Running the page with compatibility turned off was fine! Good old IE - thanks for wasting a day of my life!